# Name of an element used in Android default music player

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to create my own media player and for that purpose I would like to copy paste some ideas from the Android default music player. I have searched a lot to know what is the name of the component that I have highlighted in the figure below but I haven't found anything. If anyone knows what is this component that could be dragged up (eventually becomes a full-screen player) I would really appreciate it his/her answer.

[Figure](http://postimg.org/image/jschlhrmn/)